# Fastest way to find duplicates between two arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

There are a lot of posts on the easiest way to find duplicates in two arrays, but what is absolute fastest way? Is there a way to avoid using two for loops and get the function from `O(n^2)` time to `O(n)` time? The arrays I have contain ~1000 items each. Before running the function I check which array is longer and use that array as the `toCheckAgainst` variable.

```
var containingBoth = [];
function checkArrays(toCheck, toCheckAgainst){
 for(var i=0;i<toCheck.length;i+=1){
  for(var j=0;j<toCheckAgainst.length;j+=1){
    if (toCheck[i] === toCheckAgainst[j]) {
      containingBoth.push(toCheck[i]);
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Do the arrays contain only primitives or also objects? If only primitives, I believe something like this could work: http://jsfiddle.net/xm3w1d31/ . And I believe it follows `O(n)`

Comment: @Niles In your solution if toCheck Length is 10 and checkAgainst len is 5 then your for loops are running 60 times which is not efficent in case the arrays are large

Comment: @Ian if i run your fiddle its returning empty array even though there are dupe values in arrays you declared

Comment: @Amit.S No it doesn't - it returns an array of [2, 3]. Did you check your browser console? What browser are you testing in?

Comment: @Ian sorry mate I changed console.log to alert but did't changed the "," to "+" in brackets... My bad

Comment: @Amit.S No worries. You scared me though!

Comment: One obvious performance improvement is for the inner loop to break as soon as a duplicate is found, unless you want to count how many there are for a particular value.

Comment: @Ian this also works perfectly and helped with my understanding of Amit is doing below. RobG's suggestion would also speed it up since once a duplicate is found I wouldn't need to check the rest of the 2nd array for the particular value.

Comment: @Ian I should use the longer array for a1 and the shorter for a2. Correct? Is your solution faster than Amit.S's because he is using .indexOf?

Comment: @NilesTurner I think the better solution is to determine which is longer (a1 vs. a2) and use that for the second loop (to do less object lookups and array pushes) - something like: http://jsfiddle.net/apbo95ae/ (I also changed it to use `.hasOwnProperty()` to be more flexible in values used). I don't *know* if mine is faster (feel free to perf test it), but I would think it's faster because `indexOf` adds complexity; object lookups are fast, and there's no complexity in the loops

Answer (score 0):

This can be the another way to achieve this.Your current solution have the looping on both of the arrays and looping on the longest one which slower down the process in large arrays e.g if one longest array has 1000 vals and shorter array has only 2 in that case you are looping 1000 values to find out the dupes which can not be more than 2 in that case.

Below solution loop is only on the array which is shorter than the other array because we are only interested in dupes and even if both arrays are of same length below solution is faster because in your solution you are looping on both arrays whereas below code just loop on one.

Did some testing on comparing difference in speed in Niles code and mine see the results here [Niles Code](https://jsfiddle.net/as541986/s1jhkzry/) and [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/as541986/v8e9xy8g/) and its approximately 50% faster with the arrays of 1000 values each

```
var arr1 = ["Test1", "test2", "test3","test5","test6","test4"];
var arr2 = ["test1", "test4","test5","test6","test2","Test1"];
var result = [];
(arr1.length>arr2.length?arr2:arr1).forEach(function(key) {
    if (-1 != (arr1.length>arr2.length?arr1:arr2).indexOf(key) && -1 == result.indexOf(key)) 
        result.push(key);
}, this);
alert(result); //duplicate values arr
```

Comment: This is great. Just for my understanding, what Big-O complexity is this? Is it O(n log n) as per @deamentiaemundi's answer below?

Comment: It is O(n^2) with O(n^2) comparisons plus O(n) for the search in the result for unifying (which hasn't been asked for?). Array.indexOf() is linear search, so sorting the larger array as counterintuitive as it might seem would make the whole thing faster because you could do a binary search which is O(log n) and brings the number of comparisons down to O(n log n) if you want to do the sorting and comparing in two separate runs. It has some overhead but it will win with larger arrays and you were talking about arrays >10k entries.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited to add example code**
You can do it in O(n) if both arrays--with lengths "k" and "l" respectively--are already sorted. You can do it by merging the two arrays (not in memory, of course, just algorithmically) like in merge-sort with k+l comparisons.

If both arrays are not sorted at all you can do it in O(n log n) (e.g. with the merge-sort mentioned above) with O(n²) comparisons and because you can do your task with brute force in O(n²) already, sorting the arrays would be redundant here.

But not all sets are completely unsorted, especially if they are big. If we take quicksort as an example you can expect O(n log n) on average with O(n log n) comparisons. But be aware that the worst case of quicksort is O(n²) when the set is already sorted!

A very simple way if your arrays are sorted and contain no duplicates:
Take the individual entries of the smaller array and do a binary search for them in the larger array -> O(n log n) (binary search is O(log n) and you do it n times). The smaller array does not even have to be sorted if it is guaranteed that it contains no duplicates.

Summary: you can do it faster than O(n²). It depends on the input how fast "faster" actually gets but you can get it down to O(n) (plus a small constant) in the best case and O(n log n) on average.

```
'use strict'
var primesieve;
var buffer;
var primelimit;
function clear(where) {
  primesieve[where >>> 5] &= ~((1 << (31 - (where & 31))));
}
function get(where) {
  return ((primesieve[where >>> 5] >>> ((31 - (where & 31)))) &
  1);
}
function nextset(from) {
  while (from < primelimit && !get(from)) {
    from++;
  }
  if (from === primelimit && !get(from)) {
    return - 1;
  }
  return from;
}
function fillsieve(n) {
  var k,
  r,
  j;
  n = n + 1;
  primelimit = n - 1;
  k = Math.ceil(n / 32);
  if (typeof ArrayBuffer !== 'function') {
    buffer = new ArrayBuffer(k * 4);
  } else {
    buffer = k;
  }
  primesieve = new Uint32Array(buffer);
  while (k--) {
    primesieve[k] = 0xffffffff;
  }
  clear(0);
  clear(1);
  for (k = 4; k < n; k += 2) {
    clear(k);
  }
  r = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));
  k = 0;
  while (k < n) {
    k = nextset(k + 1);
    if (k > r || k < 0) {
      break;
    }
    for (j = k * k; j < n; j += 2 * k) {
      clear(j);
    }
  }
}
function approx_limit(prime_pi) {
  if (prime_pi < 10) {
    return 30;
  }
  // see first term of expansion of li(x)-li(2)

  return Math.ceil(prime_pi * (Math.log(prime_pi * Math.log(prime_pi))));
}
function primes(prime) {
  var ret,
  k,
  count,
  i;
  ret = [];
  k = 0;
  i = 0;
  count = prime;
  while (count--) {
    k = nextset(k + 1);
    if (k > primelimit || k < 0) {
      break;
    }
    ret[i++] = k;
  }
  return ret;
}
// very simple binary search
Array.prototype.bsearch = function(needle) {
  var mid, lo = 0;
  var hi = this.length - 1;

  while (lo <= hi) {
    mid = Math.floor((lo + hi) / 2);
    if (this[mid] > needle) {
      hi = mid - 1;
    } else if (this[mid] < needle) {
      lo = mid + 1;
    } else {
      return this[mid];
    }
  }
  // assumes no entry "-1", of course
  return -1;
};

var limit = 10 * 1000;
var a, b, b_sorted, u;
var a_length, b_length, u_length;

fillsieve(approx_limit(limit));

// the first array is filled with primes, sorted and unique
a = primes(limit);

// the second array gets filled with an unsorted amount of
// integers between the limits 0 (zero) and "limit".
b = [];
for(var i = 0;i < limit;i++){
  b[i] = Math.floor( Math.random() * (limit + 1));
}
a_length = a.length;
b_length = b.length;

console.log("Length of array a: " + a_length);
console.log("Length of array b: " + b_length);

var start, stop;
u = [];

// Brute-force
start = performance.now();
for(var i = 0; i < a_length; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j< b_length; j++){
    if(a[i] == b[j] && a[i] != u[u.length - 1]){
      u.push(a[i]);
    }
  }
}
stop = performance.now();
console.log("Brute force = " + (stop - start));
console.log("u-length = " + u.length);
console.log(u.join(","));

u = [];
b_sorted = [];
// work on copy
for(var i = 0; i < b_length; i++) b_sorted[i] = b[i];
var entry;

// Sort the unsorted array first, than do a binary search
start = performance.now();
// ECMA-script's arrays sort() function sorts lexically
b_sorted.sort(function(a,b){return a - b;});
for(var i = 0; i < a_length; i++){
  entry = b_sorted.bsearch(a[i])
  if( entry != -1 && entry != u[u.length - 1]){
    u.push(entry);
  }
}
stop = performance.now();
console.log("Binary search = " + (stop - start));
console.log("u-length = " + u.length);
console.log(u.join(","));
```

This runs on my little AMD A8-6600K in around 56 seconds with the brute force algorithm and in about 40 milliseconds (yes, *milli*seconds!) with the binary search and that number even includes the sorting of the array.